Related to integration transformation from Cartesian plane to Polar coordinates
I am working in area of wireless communication that involves extensive use of probability, random variables and stochastic geometry.
My system model is as follows: It consists of a main base station (BS) (you may consider it as radar), denoted as $BS_0$, interfering base stations (BSs) denoted as $BS_j$, $j = 1,2...$, one main sensing target, denoted as $ST_0$ and sensing targets (STs), denoted as $ST_i$. All of them are distributed as independent homogeneous Poisson Point Processes (PPPs).
I am trying to understand how equation (1) (wherein integration is in cartesian plane) is transformed into equation (2) (wherein integration is in polar coordinates).
$L_1 = \exp(-\gamma_b \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}1-\mathbb{E}(\exp(-s.a.H))\text{d}x)$ ---(1)
where $\gamma_b$ is the density of BSs, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Cartesian plane, $\mathbb{E}(.)$ denotes Expectation operator, $\exp(.)$ is exponential function, $s$ is related to Laplace, $a$ is constant, $H$ is exponentially distributed random variable and $x$ is locations of interfering BSs.
This expression (1) is transformed into polar co-ordinates as
$L_2 = \exp(-2\pi\gamma_b \int_{d_{b,t}}^{d_{bj,t}}1-\mathbb{E}(\exp(-s.a.H))d_{bj,t}\text{d}d_{bj,t})$ ---(2)
where $d_{b,t}$ denotes distance between $BS_0$ and $ST_0$, $d_{bj,t}$ is distance between $BS_j$ and $ST_0$.
I understood that whenever we transform Cartesian plane into polar coordinates, then $2\pi$ comes into picture. But, my query is how $d_{bj,t}\text{d}d_{bj,t}$ is obtained in equation (2).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
